# how to make a div expand to wrap a dynamic content in css

Tags: css

I have a wrapper div which i want to expand to wrap the content that is dynamically generated. The content generated is a table, that increases based on the number of returned results.

```
css for wrapper div
#wrapperDiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:1341px;
    left: 0px;
    border: 5px solid #408080;
    overflow:hidden;
}

css for table inside the wrapper div
#Table {
    position: absolute;
    width: 940px;
    height: 319px;
    left: 409px;
    top: 215px;
}
```

it doesn't show all the results, when i change overflow to visible it shows all but the results goes beyond the wrapper div, and i still want the footer div to always be at the bottom.

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of little problems here :)

First: You have set your height to a fixed value "1341px". Because you have set it to this value your div will never get higher than 1341px. You can use min-height if you want the div to only scale when the content gets bigger than 1341px.

Second: Your #Table is positioned Absolute. Wich means that the parent will always ignore the size of the #Table element when rendering.

i suggest you have a quick look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp for some more information on this toppic.

Try the following css:

```
#wrapperDiv {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height:1341px;
left: 0px;
border: 5px solid #408080;
overflow:hidden;}

#Table {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 940px;
height: 319px;
margin-left: 409px;
margin-top: 215px;}
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: thanks for your solution, it work like magic for me, i appreciate.

Comment: Good to hear :) would you mind validating my comment as answer? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As someone say it in comments, `height: auto;` should works fine. But your code is a mess. I think you don't understand how css position works;
Let's create a container (`.Container`) and fill the parent (`.Container { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden; }`). And simply add `{ position: absolute; width: 100%; bottom: 0; height: auto; max-height: 100%; overflow: auto; }` for dymanic content block.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #F72F4E;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 5px solid #408080;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 0; //or top: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<main class="Container">
  <div class="Content">Dynamic Content</div>
</main>
```